# Shadow terminator artifacts issues

Tags: shadows, artifacts

I work with Blender 2.81a and I have a problem with some artifacts in the shadows of objects with smooth shading. Based on the release note of Blender 2.81 ,(https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-81/), I expected this problem to be solved. There’s a note with a comparative screenshot saying: “Reduced shadow terminator artifacts for bump mapping with diffuse BSDFs.“

There’s no detail about the issue. There’s a mention about “bump mapping”. I have another scene with bump mapping and the problem is the same as in my test shown below. Here’s a screenshot of my test below.

The only solution right now is to increase of the number of polygons with a “Subdivision Surface” modifier. However that makes a crazy amount of polygons and the modifier cannot fit all situations.

Another element of solution is about the light. I noticed that happens particularly when there’s one directional light in the scene like a sun light. Increasing the “Angle” parameter creates a smoother effect. Too much of this becomes blurry and unrealistic. My screenshot shows a sun with the angle 6.4 degrees.

These artifacts only happen in Cycles. Eevee seems to be correct.

I expected this problem to be solved. However it is still present. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: yes it was supposed to be solved, maybe in the next versions? And yes, the solution seems to be increasing the light size ("Angle" in 2.8)

Answer (score 9):

Edit 2021-11-26: a better solution is available as of Blender 3.0, added to the answer below.

#### Blender 3.0+

A setting called `Geometry offset` is enabled by default, hence the artifact should not occur anymore.

The geometry offset value can be tweaked in the object properties `Object Properties \ Shading \ Shadow Terminator`.

`Geometry offset` preserves the shadow's location and color, unlike `Shading offset` (previously called `Shadow terminator offset` in Blender 2.9).

Further details in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pr1K7kvZzCc&t=492s).

#### Blender 2.9.x

In blender 2.9, a `Shadow terminator offset` parameter has been added under `Object Properties \ Shading`. It is set to 0 by default, increasing its value fixes the problem.

Demo and explanations in [this video](https://youtu.be/oecXkpAoq9U?t=33).

### Earlier blender versions

The artifact disappears when adding more geometry, either by subdividing the mesh, or adding a subsurf modifier.