# jagged render using cycles, smooth with eevee

Tags: rendering

I've checked other questions with these terms but no answers.

When I render an image with default settings in eevee, I get smooth shadows, when I render using cycles the shadows on  my snowman show some sharp edges.  What can I do to get a better render using cycles since I plan to use this mode for more in depth animations in the future.

[image: Evee Render]
[image: Cycles Render]

Comment: Terminator issues. Try increasing subdivisions and use smooth shading. Read these related posts: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160211/shadow-terminator-artifacts-issues and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p

Comment: Note that the shadows in the image from eevee also have jagged edges. You need more subdivisions.