# Texture not fully being rendered

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm fairly new at using blender but I've seen a lot of cool stuff and wanted to try it out for myself.
So I followed some tutorials, one of which is modelling the earth using textures.

After this I tried to model another planet with the same techniques. However, when rendering the scene, the textures are not fully rendered on my own created planet.
As you can see in the rendered image, there is a piece on the edge at where the light hits that is not being rendered.

Can anyone explain to me why this is?

I'm using blender 2.9 with the cycles render on CPU.[image]

Comment: I don't see what corner you are referring to. In any case, you should add subdivision modifier to your objects to make them rounder (and also smooth shade).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will look into subdivision and smoothing.
My choice of words is indeed not good ( English is not my native language), You can see on the red planet, in the middle where the light does not hit and the shade begins, there is a piece which is not rendered. It shows as a black corner,....

Comment: related -- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160211/shadow-terminator-artifacts-issues

Comment: Cycles is all about realism while EEVEE is basically faking everything (The shadow will be smooth if you change the engine to EEVEE)- You need subdivision surface so the shadow won't be blocky