# Shading problem with displacement

Tags: shaders, light, displacement, shadows

I am having a problem with my shading when using displacement.
[image]

This is what it should look like from the tutorial I am following (https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=urQT2tDV1qw)

[image]

Here are my nodes (the group just sets up generated color coordinates)

[image]
if anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

edit:
here is it without adaptive subdivision:
[image]

Comment: Hi! do you have enough geometry?
Did you add the subdivision surface modifier?

Comment: Add a blend file or try to analyze the tutorial step by step.
Also try applying transformations (ctrl+A) if you have scaled it in middle.

Comment: so I just tried redoing the whole scene and I'm getting the same problem. The screenshot above is using adaptive subdivision but the problem still exists when using a basic subdivision modifier. When not using experimental subdivision I am getting an odd creasing where the edges would be

Comment: try to add your blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/

It would easy to look into the issue that way :D

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=7nXklEEE" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/7nXklEEE/)

Comment: You're missing the displacement node, my friend.

Comment: This look to me as if it might have a 'Shadow Terminator' problem. See [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/197205/35559)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have chosen Displacement and bump in the displacement settings, which is resulting in a bump at the edges.

Try changing it to displacement only.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to plug your calculation into the *Height* input of a *Displacement* node before the *Material Output*.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? 
When I try adding the displacement node to the set up it deforms the object!
I don't think you should need it since, the coordinates are already manipulated.
(sorry I don't know the exact terminology)

Comment: What Default Cube is trying to set up is a displacement to make a perfect sphere from a primitive, so he normalizes to displace out 1m in all directions and subtracts out the original mesh position.  It's not necessary and sometimes he does weird stuff at the beginning of his tuts. (Afaik)