# How to get rid of inaccurate, jagged mesh shadows

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, mesh, shaders, lighting

I am using Blender Cycles for a project. At the time of rendering, I am getting inaccurate mesh shadows, as seen in the screenshot below. How can I make sure the shadows are rendered properly?

[image: Screenshot showing the effect]

Comment: I think it would also help if you were to provide a screenshot of the mesh, both wireframe and solid. The material is not translucent, right?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160211/shadow-terminator-artifacts-issues https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably the *Terminator Effect*, when Blender struggles to give smooth shadow, you can either increase the sun *Angle* value, or in the *Object* panel > *Shading*, increase the *Shadow Terminator* value:

[image]

Comment: Would you explain what this value does ?

Comment: Sorry, technically I would not be able to explain how it fixes the Terminator Effect problem. But Terminator Effect happens when the light is too sharp, it looks like in that case it's impossible to smooth the surfaces.