# I have a problem with normal map rendering in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, normal-map

I use hard edges on my low-poly model and in these places a terrible defect appears - my beautiful normals become broken, borders appear along all the hard edges... I baked this map in Marmoset with these hard edges.  I have beautiful render in Eevee, there are no problems in Substance and Marmoset.  But my favorite Cycles has this awful bug when rendering with hard edges.  Help me solve this problem please.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark-shadow-artefacts https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/160211/shadow-terminator-artifacts-issues https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1998/cycles-shadows-on-smooth-shaded-mesh-strange-behavior/1999#1999

Comment: Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?